# std::bind and overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

Please refer the following code snippet. I want to use the `std::bind` for overloaded function `foobar`. It calls only the method with no arguments.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
class Client
{  
  public :  
  void foobar(){std::cout << "no argument" << std::endl;}
  void foobar(int){std::cout << "int argument" << std::endl;}
  void foobar(double){std::cout << "double argument" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Client cl;  
    //! This works 
    auto a1 = std::bind(static_cast<void(Client::*)(void)>(&Client::foobar),cl);
    a1();
    //! This does not
    auto a2= [&](int)
    {
        std::bind(static_cast<void(Client::*)(int)>(&Client::foobar),cl);
    };
    a2(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` in your lambda.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `placeholders` for the unbound arguments:

```
auto a2 = std::bind(static_cast<void(Client::*)(int)>(&Client::foobar), cl,
                    std::placeholders::_1);
a2(5);
```

You can also perform the binding with a lambda capture (note that this is binds `cl` by reference, not by value):

```
auto a2 = [&](int i) { cl.foobar(i); };
```

Comment: And the by-value capture can be done with `[&,i]` or `[=,&cl]`.