# bind to overloaded method using boost::function

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

How do I achieve the following overloaded method call

```
class Foo {
    void bind(const int,boost::function<int (void)> f);
    void bind(const int,boost::function<std::string (void)> f);
    void bind(const int,boost::function<double (void)> f);
};
```

First attempt

```
SomeClass c;
Foo f;
f.bind(1,boost::bind(&SomeClass::getint,ref(c));
f.bind(1,boost::bind(&SomeClass::getstring,ref(c)));
f.bind(1,boost::bind(&SomeClass::getdouble,ref(c)));
```

Then I found a [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064698/stdbind-and-overloaded-function) so tried this:-

```
f.bind(static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int,boost::function<int(void)>)>(1,boost::bind(&SomeClass::getint)));
```

which looks ugly but might work?

but gives and error

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' to 'void (__cdecl Foo::* )(int,boost::function<Signature>)'
```

Any ideas I can make this overloading work. I suspect type erasure is occuring but the compiler obviously recognises the overloaded methods since Foo.cpp compiles fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible answer you link to is solving a different problem: choosing between function overloads when taking a pointer to that function. The solution is to explicitly cast to the correct function type, since only the correct function is convertible to that type.

Your problem is different: choosing between overloads when calling the function, when there's no clear conversion to any of the overloaded parameter types. You can either convert explicitly to the function type:

```
f.bind(1,boost::function<int (void)>(boost::bind(&SomeClass::getint,boost::ref(c))));
```

or, in C++11, use a lambda:

```
f.bind(1,[&]{return c.getint();});
```

(and you'd probably prefer `std::function` to `boost::function` in C++11).

Comment: Works perfectly, and yes I switched to std::function.
I'm guessing there is no way of having the compiler deduce the casting arguments through the use of a factory function?